# Can ConTeXt do what luaTeX does?

Tags: luatex, context

I am aware that ConTeXt is a macro package whereas luaTeX is an engine. As far as I know, luaTeX is a plain TeX + Lua as an embedded scripting language. Furthermore, ConTeXt can use Lua.

**My question is where are the differences? In other words, what are some situations in which one overcomes the other (i.e. advantages and disadvantages)?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Contrary to what Gaussler says, from circa 2018 there's a new format called ConTeXt LMTX (Lua, Metapost, TeX, XML) using a new engine called LuaMetaTeX. I'll try to summarize some advantages and disadvantages wrt aspects I'm familiar with. Also, by simplicity I list both ConTeXt (format) and LuaMetaTeX (engine) features.

**EDIT:** Gaussler is right wrt average users. ConTeXt MkIV and LuaTeX (be OpTeX, LaTeX, Plain, etc.) should be capable (theoretically) of doing essentially the same things. It's only when you need more tuning or features that differences become clear.

### Advantages

- Extended macro parser: additionally to `#1`...`#9` you have `#+` to pass an argument as-is, `#-` to discard an argument and `#0` to gobble an argument. Companion primitives are also added. They aren't meant to be used by average users, I think. Details here: http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/evenmore.pdf
- Finer control of boxes which allows you to e.g. "slice" text lines (http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/magazines/mag-1105-mkiv.pdf). It's possible, but more complicated using LuaTeX.
- Finer control of text directions. LuaMetaTeX no longer supports four directions as LuaTeX did. Instead it supports two directions and presents a orientation model. Example uses include vertical typesetting: http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/followingup.pdf. Very nice for CJK and Mongolian.
- New interface(s) to Metapost/Metafun. Aditya Mahajan has already read a nice summary of what is possible with such interfaces if you want to write your own: https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/new-metafun-interface/ Predefined interfaces are listed here: http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luametafun.pdf. I mention them because Metapost by itself (as `mpost`) doesn't support such additions.
- Partial SVG support via Metapost (AFAIK ConTeXt MkIV resorts to external dependencies). This include SVG fonts (e.g. emoji ones), although with some tweaks. Examples here: http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/svg-lmtx.pdf
- A smaller binary.

### Disadvantages

- Compiled libraries (.so/.dll) aren't supported by default. This is because LuaMetaTeX doesn't fully support them and you have to include your own Lua libraries. Also, and unlike ConTeXt with LuaTeX, you need an additional flag `--permitloadlib`. According to LuaMetaTeX manual, "the reason for having this as option is the wish for security [...], so this might give an extra feeling of protection": http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luametatex.pdf
- Not really a disadvantage, but a caveat. LuaMetaTeX uses Lua 5.4 which is in active development, so minor differences (and bugs) wrt Lua 5.3 will be there.

Comment: One thing I’ve never been able to understand is why we don’t drop this horrible `#1–#9` scheme for arguments where you constantly have to worry about doubling or *n*-upling the number of `#`’s. We should use `#<a unique string>` instead, with no `##` or `########`. So then we could do e.g. `\def\myindex#subscript#superscript{^{#superscript}_{#subscript}}`.

Comment: @Gaussler ConTeXt partially solves the naming situations via a preprocessor, so I suppose a change in the binary isn't necessary. Such a radical change would introduce a lot of bugs if included in the engine, I think. Wrt hashes, I guess this hasn't changed because nobody has proposed a better alternative.

Comment: As is evident from another post I made today, I would very much prefer TeX to behave more like a normal programming language with respect to how it expands its commands. This would make the language a lot more predictable and accessible for programmers. I cannot help wonder why packages that are celebrated as masterpieces of TeX programming (e.g. `siunitx`) would have been completely trivial introductory exercises in any other programming language than TeX.

Comment: @Gaussler TeX is a macro processor not a programming language, so the comparison is ill-posed.  You could compare TeX to something like the C preprocessor or a restricted subset of Lisp.  BTW, hash doubling is very necessary, otherwise you couldn't do `\def\foo#1{\def\bar##1{#1/##1}}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke TeX certainly has programming language features. Hash doubling would not be necessary if TeX were designed as I suggested. Then you could simply call your variables `#1` and `##1` different things, like `#firstvar` and `#secondvar` (of course, the macro processing would in general work very differently). For the same reason, in most programming languages, I can have a globally defined variable `s` and still use `s` as the name of an argument in a function; then the language will usually just ignore the original variable `s` in the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

ConTeXt (in its newest version) runs exclusively on LuaTeX. So ConTeXt can do everything LuaTeX can.

Comment: context in its newest version runs on luametatex, not luatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Close enough.

Comment: not really. luametatex is so different that it wasn't possible to create a latex format with it without lots of tweeks (and perhaps it broke again after the last changes).

Comment: @Gaussler You're wrong, really wrong. Hans Hagen has made significant changes in LuaMetaTeX which make it unusable with traditional formats.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio And yet, for the average user, the difference probably hardly matters. The important thing to the OP seems to be whether ConTeXt can do the same things LuaTeX (with another format) can, and unless you doing some complicated constructions, the answer is probably “yes”.

Comment: @Gaussler Oh, well, in this case you're right (Hans itself expressed his intention of keeping roughly the same user interface). Just in case, I wrote an answer for those interested in new goodies.